# Romanian voice for blind people narrator windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Do you guys know any software for blind people to work on windows 7, but the voice has to be in romanian, any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check with any group in Romainia that supports persons with vision impairment.  They will be a good starting point.  I know the main group here in Canada (C.N.I.B) has everthing anyone would need.